# How to span a Tkinter frame inside of a Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have just started using Tkinter and I have a frame insdie of a canvas placed using the create_window funcion so that I may have a working scrollbar for my program. The issue is the Text widgets that I place in the frame inside of the canvas is not spanning horizontally inside the canvas and I have no idea how to make this happen. I have tried using pack() or grid() and grid_rowconfigure, but if I don't use create_window then the bar on my scroll bar disappears. I can't seem to find any post that addresses this issue, but I may be wrong. Here is the snippet of my code that deals with the GUI of this window:

```
root = Tk()
# create top part
top=Frame(root)
# create a canvas to scroll
holder = Canvas(top)
# create scroll bar
scroll = Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL, command=holder.yview)
# configure scrollbar for canvas
holder.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
holder.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: holder.configure(scrollregion=holder.bbox("all")))
# create frame for content inside canvas and add it to the canvas
content = Frame(holder, relief=RAISED)
holder.create_window((0,0), window=content, anchor='nw')
# create bottom part
bottom = Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=18)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=50)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
holder.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
bottom.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

num=0
for site in sites:
    temp=Text(content, height = 5)
    temp.configure(state= DISABLED)
    temp.pack(fill=X, side=TOP, padx= 5, pady= 5)
    siteBoxes.append(temp)
    num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should update `scrollregion` of `holder` whenever the internal frame `content` (not the canvas `holder`) is resized.

Second, you can update the width of the internal frame `content` whenever the canvas `holder` is resized.

Below is the updated code:

```py
root = Tk()
# create top part
top=Frame(root)
# create a canvas to scroll
holder = Canvas(top)
# create scroll bar
scroll = Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL, command=holder.yview)
# configure scrollbar for canvas
holder.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
### --- expand the width of the internal frame to the width of canvas
holder.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: holder.itemconfigure(internal, width=e.width))
# create frame for content inside canvas and add it to the canvas
content = Frame(holder, relief=RAISED)
### --- update scrollregion whenever the internal frame is resized
content.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: holder.configure(scrollregion=holder.bbox("all")))
### --- save the item ID of the internal frame
internal = holder.create_window((0,0), window=content, anchor='nw')
# create bottom part
bottom = Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=18)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=50)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
holder.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
bottom.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

num=0
for site in sites:
    temp=Text(content, height = 5)
    temp.configure(state= DISABLED)
    temp.pack(fill=X, side=TOP, padx= 5, pady= 5)
    siteBoxes.append(temp)
    num += 1

root.mainloop()
```